# Testing Show input field when select option is chosen in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have a select field and an input field, i want to create a test for them, so that the input field 'Age' is shown when the select option is 'Female'. But i got an error, can someone help me in that?

> Error: TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible
> element with the role "textbox" and name `/age/i`

```
  const genderOption = watch("gender");

    <input name="gender" role="combobox">
      <button class="combobox-arrow"></button>
      <ul role="listbox">
       <li
        role="option"
        value="Male"
       ><span>Male</span></li>
       <li
        role="option"
        value="Female"
       ><span>Female</span></li>
      </ul>
    {genderOption === "Female" && (
      <label for="ageInput">Age</label>
      <input
      id="ageInput"
      type="text"
      name="Age"
      >
    )}
```

```
const genderInput = screen.getByRole("combobox", {
    name: /gender/i,
  });

  userEvent.click(genderInput);
  const optionElement = screen.getByRole("option", {
    name: /female/i,
  });
  await userEvent.click(optionElement);

  const ageElement = screen.getByRole("textbox", {
    name: /age/i,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing for appearance and disappearance with React Testing Library is sometimes tricky to get the timing fully right. You should use the `findByX` query to wait for the element to be present.

https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#1-using-findby-queries

```
const genderInput = screen.getByRole("combobox", {
    name: /gender/i,
  });

  userEvent.click(genderInput);
  const optionElement = screen.getByRole("option", {
    name: /female/i,
  });
  await userEvent.click(optionElement);

  const ageElement = await screen.findByRole("textbox", {
    name: /age/i,
  });
```